# Tranferring Photo Library from iPhone to iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos

I am planning to buy a new iPhone and I was wondering how to transfer my entire Photo Library from the old iPhone to the new one, keeping the same folder organization and without losing photos' metadata (e.g., creation date, GPS location, etc.).

I don't want to do it via iCloud (as I don't have enough space available), so is there another (free) way to perform this action?

Comment: How do you currently back up your photos? How many photos do you have?

Comment: I have around 1000 photos. I backup my Phone through iTunes (and I regularly download my photos on my MacBookPro Photo app).

Comment: If there are already in the Photos app on the MBP can't you just sync them to the new phone from there?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I think that transferring photos from the MBP to the iPhone will create a separate (and independent) folder in the iPhone photo gallery. On the other hand, I'd like to have the old photos to be in the same folder of the new photos that I'll take with my new iPhone.